# Distro that I can load into RAM?

Tags: boot, usb, boot-to-ram

Is there a modified version of Ubuntu that I can choose to load to RAM on start up? Kinda like the LiveCD, but that can be easily modified (ie: I can install stuff) when I choose to boot from disk.

The idea is to install it to a USB drive. I know there's [something similar](http://www.slax.org/) but slax is lacking in many departments. A "full" version Ubuntu would be better.

A LiveUSB installation seems to be pretty close to what I want, but apparently I have to choose whether or not it will be persistent by the time I install it. I want to be able to choose that every time I boot.

Comment: Umm, what is wrong with installing normal Ubuntu to USB stick?

Comment: @Olli Then I have to keep the USB plugged in all the time. I want to be able to remove the drive if I need to and the system should still run.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's definitely technically possible, see for example http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Booting_the_CD-ROM (`docache` parameter).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is parameter `toram`, which you can give to recent Ubuntu livecd's at boot time, recent meaning 10.04 or newer. That'll load everything to RAM (assuming you have enough RAM to hold it), and afterwards you can remove CD (or USB stick) and continue using Ubuntu normally.

Comment: Yes, this works yet in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

*This answer includes text which I used to answer a different question but it is placed here in order to illustrate and give a visual guide, which you probably already have.*

In the majority of the cases, Ubuntu (almost any version) will run perfectly in a live session, and placed in a USB with "Persistent" data options, you will have what you wish.

The problem will be that, when you unplug the USB memory/hdd, the disk will be unmounted, and that way -even when you re-plug, the USB will be unreachable, unless you do something in order to recover the mount point to the USB.

Nevertheless, all the running applications will continue running even if you unplug or unmount the USB.

A good idea to try is to make sure that all the processes you need are loaded at startup, which will ensure that the processes will be running at the time you unplug the USB.

Me myself have done that with just a few applications. I am using [Israel Remix Team](http://ultimateeditionisrael.freeforums.org/) distro which is already pre-loaded with lots of applications in advance, and this way, when the application is loaded, I can unplug the USB memory and the program continues the run.

I haven't tried hard resources demanding programs, but in my case:

1. File sharing continues working and
   sharing files, even when those files are in a fixed hard disk drive, other than the USB file system.
2. VLC continues playing a radio
   station broadcast without problems,
3. Yakuake continues the work and does
   what I request unless I wish
   something of the unplugged USB
4. Google Chrome continues surfing the
   web and allow me to do several
   things like monitoring ip-cameras.

The only problem is when I try to plug the USB in order to run a new application, which won't be achieved by the currently running OS instance, so I have to reboot in order to start a new application beside those which are loaded at startup.

Another good Idea would be to use the feature to "Remember Currently Running Applications" in the "System/Preferences/Startup Applications" preferences window. Which (when enabled) will "remember" all the programs that you are using and will re-open them after a reboot or when starting the system for the first time in a day.

If you wish to remove an application from this feature simply close it and go to this function and press the "Remember Currently Running Application" in order to refresh the list of the programs that will be opened the next time.

A screenshot is placed here in order to illustrate.

[image]

Then, taking in consideration what I say above, it is worth to perform the next experiment:

### USB Startup Disk guide:

First of all, you can make a USB Startup Disk using a GUI, which will ease the task. Unfortunately, this can only be done when inside of an ubuntu system, both Live session or Installed system can do the trick.

I know that people may suggest you to follow a few other successful procedures, but in my case I will talk about the "Startup Disk Creator".

In several Linux Distributions you can find this tool in the "System/Administration/Startup Disk Creator". I strongly suggest you to try the [Israel Remix Team](http://israelremixteam.freeforums.org/index.php), the one I use, but almost any distribution should feature this tool.

A screenshot is placed here for you to see the tool when recently opened:

[image]

Make sure that you have downloaded your prefered Ubuntu distribution prior to try this in a live session.

In the "Make Startup Disk" window, click in the "Other" button in the top right side in order to choose your Linux distribution's iso that you previously downloaded and have already inserted the USB that you are going to use for the process. Both the ".iso" and the USB should appear in their respective areas.

[image]

NOTE: If you are going to use a pre-burned DVD for the process, simply insert the DVD in the tray and it will be listed into the sources list as shown in the next image:

[image]

In my case, my 4 GB USB memory is having a live session already installed, what I am going to do first is to clic in the "Erase Disk" in order to gather enough space for the system, after which I will get the options for the data handling, on which I am going to choose the amount of disk size that I wish to use for saving data and configurations (like installing programs, etc.) I am going to use 1.4 GB for that purpose.

[image]

Now I click the "Make Startup Disk", and the copy process is going to happen.

[image]

After which the GRUB should also be installed. Unfortunately the GRUB install process was too fast so I couldn't take the shot.

The persistence file will be created.

[image]
[image]

Then you will be able to start from that USB. Note that you can use both USB memories or USB hard disk drives, even when in use with an adaptor, IDE-to-USB or SATA-to-USB.

[image]

This should work as you wish, at least it makes me feel happy with the results.

Good luck!

Comment: I think it's good idea to link to original answer too

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right Olli, sorry. Original links can be reached at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key/28500#28500 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/27824/how-to-make-a-program-show-on-startup/27917#27917

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on JUST this. A livecd-to-usb setup wasn't working very well for me. I have created a modified version of the "local" script for ubuntu server 11.04. After applying the patch (or hand editing local with the changes of course) you only need update-iniramfs -u, and boot linux with a "ramboot" kernel argument, and your system will boot a normal linux system fully into ram. Making persistent changes is as easy as rsync'ing the ramdisk filesystem onto the boot-device. In my case, a usb-pen, but it could easily be any suitable bootable block device. You can, of course, just reboot without the "ramboot" argument and make changes, as you will be back on the block device, then reboot into ramboot again, but there is no need, except it makes it very clear when you're in which state.

0) "sudo su"

(you don't have to do this step, but then you will need to make sure you sudo everything that might require it) I tend to just "sudo su" when I'm doing this type of systems modifications.

1) download or copy/paste the contents of this patch to a file:

"/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/ramboot.patch" --couldn't include pastebin, newbie. 
**included at end**

2) cd /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts; cp local local.bak   #just in case

3) patch local ramboot.patch

This applies the changes defined in ramboot.patch, to your local script. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local is the normal bootup script configurator which configures the rootmount function for init. The patch was created by "diff local local.modified > ramboot.patch"

4) cp /bin/busybox /usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin/busybox

This makes your initramfs.img file slightly larger then it would be normally, but the difference is about 1.5 megabytes, not major. I wanted the human readable output from df -h, which the stripped down busybox's df doesn't support. If you care about keeping the 300k version of busybox around, make sure to cp /usr/lib/initramfs-tools/bin/busybox /small_busybox, then return it to it's former name/location after step 5.

5) update-initramfs -u

6) *optional* you will most likely want to create a /etc/grub.d/06_custom, with the kernel argument "ramboot" included, and a title that implies that.

(or 40_custom if you want the ramboot menu entry to be at the end of the list, instead of at the top)
e.g. 06_custom -- couldn't include pastebin link, newbie here.

you will need to fill in your correct kernel-version and initrd.img-verion and also the filesystem uuid of your root device into this 06_custom file or else it will not work.

you can find the kernel/initrd.img information by just looking in /boot/ with "ls /boot" and the following command should output your root filesystem uuid:

blkid|grep `df /|grep dev|cut -d ' ' -f1`|cut -d '"' -f2

Once your 06_custom has the correct uuid, kernel and initrm.img paths and file names, you can update-grub, and try it out!

7) update-grub to add the custom entries to your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.

Note: I have a small system with the root partition only including about 1.2g of data to copy into ram. If your system doesn't have enough spare memory, this script will safely boot normally (or at least try!) I found remastersys, and persistent usb-casper installs to not exactly be suitable for my needs.

This is used on a scst-iscsi server currently, and it's only real weakness is that if you don't save changes to the system, and lose power, or some other mistake (init 0, oh no, I forgot to check in my work back to subversion! disaster!) then the ramdisk system doesn't make anything persistent. I don't have a ton of air-time on this config yet, but since I had looked around for this type of information, found lots of ways that were not exactly suitable, or just plain confusing to me, I thought I'd put this out there. perhaps it will save someone a little teeth pulling *8^)

remastersys and the root-ro scripts helped me to this point. they are both useful but different projects. remastersys packages your running system, to both deploy/clone, or just run as a live.iso version of the system, or backup I guess. root-ro is a dual-ramdisk blockdevice-filesystem mounted union-style, with the ramdisk writeable, and the blockdev read-only. then to sync you can just remount the blockdev rw, rsync once branch to the other, and remount it ro. This was almost perfect, but I wanted the usb-pen to be unmounted/able to be removed and the system would maintain it's state, which this solution does.

root-ro bottom of the page -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash

remastersys -- http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html

You can easily rsync or copy -r from the ramboot (mounted on /) and the disk/device which it came from originally when running in ram, to make that change "persistent". 
I save the uuid of the device that the ramboot booted from, so you can always find it afterwards. It is in /.bootdisk_byuuid on the ramdisk, and you could easily set a script to mount this device somewhere, do the rsync, and umount it again, and call that script "ramtodisk" or whatever.

NB! you may want to back up your /boot/initrd.img  file so in case something goes wrong, your system is still bootable. I saved mine to /boot/initrd while doing work on this. when I had glitches with grub/init, I just edited my initrd to point to the backup /boot/initrd file and got back to debugging.  anyways, I am guessing that this is more guidelines not cookbook. have fun! it takes my 1.2gig system 9:30ish to boot on usb 1.1, 1:30-45 on usb 2.0, and ~=35 seconds on usb 3.0 to load into ram.  more and more juicy every year! *8^)

here's ramboot.patch

```
2a3,13
> parse_cmdline() {
>     RAM=""
>     for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
>         case $x in
>           ramboot)
>               RAM="Yes" ;;
>             quiet)
>                 quiet=y ;;
>         esac
>     done
> }
66c77
<
---
>       parse_cmdline
90,91c101,164
<       # Mount root
<       mount ${roflag} ${FSTYPE:+-t ${FSTYPE} }${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} ${rootmnt}
---
>       # Mount root - custom ramboot.patch
>       # By: Justin Perkins -- 4/25/12 Email: justin.perkins@vm-labs.com
>       if [ -z "${RAM}" ]; then
>               mount ${roflag} ${FSTYPE:+-t ${FSTYPE} }${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} ${rootmnt}
>       else
>               mkdir /ramboot
>               mount ${roflag} -t ${FSTYPE} ${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} /ramboot
>               log_begin_msg "Detecting system resources"
>               size=$(df|grep ramboot|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f3)
>               datasize=${size}
>               size=$(expr ${size} + ${size} / 20 )    #5% more to be sure
>               freespace=$(awk '/^MemFree:/{f=$2} /^Cached:/{c=$2} END{print f+c}' /proc/meminfo)
>               log_end_msg
>               if [ "${freespace}" -lt "${size}" ] ; then
>                       echo "Not enough system RAM, ${freespace}k > ${size}k."
>                       echo "Attempting normal rootmount."
>                       mount ${roflag} ${FSTYPE:+-t ${FSTYPE} }${ROOTFLAGS} ${ROOT} ${rootmnt}
>               else
>                       if [ "$quiet" != "y" ] ; then
>                               tstart_min=$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4|cut -d : -f2)
>                               tstart_sec=$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4|cut -d : -f3)
>                               mount -t tmpfs -o size=100% none ${rootmnt}
>                               cd ${rootmnt}
>                               size=$(df -h|grep ramboot|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f3)     #reuse size
>                               echo "System size: ${size} (${datasize}k) this may take a couple of minutes."
>                               log_begin_msg "Copying system files into RAM"
>                               echo -e -n "\b"
>                               cp -rfa /ramboot/* ${rootmnt} &
>                               pid=$!
>                               while [ ! ${pid} == "done" ] ; do
>                                       alive=$(ps -o pid,args|grep -E ${pid}|grep -v grep)
>                                       alive=$(echo ${alive}|cut -d ' ' -f1)
>                                       if [ -z ${alive} ] ; then pid="done" ; fi
>                                       printf "."
>                                       sleep 1
>                               done
>                               log_end_msg
>                               echo ${ROOT} > ${rootmnt}/.bootdisk_byuuid
>                               tend_min=$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4|cut -d : -f2)
>                               tend_sec=$(date|cut -d ' ' -f4|cut -d : -f3)
>                               if [ ${tend_sec} -lt ${tstart_sec} ] ; then
>                                       tend_sec=$(expr ${tend_sec} + 60)
>                                       tend_min=$(expr ${tend_min} - 1)
>                               fi
>                               if [ ${tend_min} -lt ${tstart_min} ] ; then
>                                       tend_min=$(expr ${tend_min} + 60)
>                           fi
>                           tduration_min=$(expr ${tend_min} - ${tstart_min})
>                           tduration_sec=$(expr ${tend_sec} - ${tstart_sec})
>                           echo "Copy complete, duration: $tduration_min minutes $tduration_sec seconds."
>                           freespace=$(awk '/^MemFree:/{f=$2} END{print f}' /proc/meminfo)
>                           freespace=$(expr ${freespace} + 425000)         #this accounts for the temporal settling issue
>                           echo "You have approximately ${freespace}k free RAM after loading the ramboot."
>                           if [ ${freespace} -lt "502400" ] ; then echo "Warning! you have critically low system RAM free after ramboot." ; fi
>
>                   else
>                           cp -rfa /ramboot/* ${rootmnt}
>                           echo ${ROOT} > ${rootmnt}/.bootdisk_byuuid
>                           freespace=$(awk '/^MemFree:/{f=$2} END{print f}' /proc/meminfo)
>                           if [ ${freespace} -lt "102400" ] ; then echo "Warning! you have critically low system RAM free after ramboot." ; fi
>                   fi
>           fi
>           umount /ramboot
>   fi      #end custom ramboot.patch
```

06_custom

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
#uuid_<placeholder>, and vmlinuz-<placeholder>, and initrd.img-<placeholder> and
#set root='(hd0,2)' need to be replaced with your system's values, although, if you
#get the hd0,2 wrong, but the uuid correct, grub will grep around and find it anyhow. 
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux Custom-Ramboot" {
    recordfail
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root uuid_placeholder
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-<placeholder> root=UUID=<uuid-placeholder> ro ramboot
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-<placeholder>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think puppy linux is now based on ubuntu, and is very small and easily load into RAM.

Comment: Well not all versions. But the question was about full blown Ubuntu in to RAM ;)

Comment: It is OT to point to other distros.