# How do I Add Cairo Dock with OpenGL to Startup?

Tags: startup, dock, cairo

Probably a dumb question, I have just started using linux again, since college 5 years ago, and getting back into the swing of things. I would like to add cairo dock to my startup and just cant figure out how for some reason, thanks.

Comment: Have you read this Q&A?  What are you struggling with?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/27824/how-to-start-applications-at-startup

Answer (score 4):

follow the [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27824/how-to-start-applications-at-startup) and you can specify in the command option which backend to use when running cairo-dock by specifying it as an option.

Run with OpenGL backend

```
cairo-dock -o
```

Run with Cario backend

```
cairo-dock -c
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should check here where there is another question on how to run applications at startup:

[How to start applications at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27824/how-to-start-applications-at-startup)

Answer (score 3):

While the dock is running, right click on the dock. In the drop down menu there's an option to start cairo-dock on startup. Select it. Done.

Comment: to run cairo-dock open a terminal and execute `cairo-dock &` and follow the instruction...